# A coding error poped up while trying to add a random question from a question bank in moodle 3.6

Tags: mysql, mariadb, moodle

I'm receiving this error message while trying to add a random question from a question bank in moodle 3.6:

> codingerror
>   Detectado un error de codificación, debe ser corregido por un programador: moodle_database::get_in_or_equal() does not accept empty arrays

The regular questions (one specific question at instance) work fine, but for random questions from a bank (the useful tool in Moodle) do not. I tried importing questions, creating new ones, flushing all the caches.

I expect to add a random question from a question bank into an exam module.